# All Liquid Malt Extract without boiling

Tags: lme

Is there any recipe for brewing a all Liquid Malt Extract without boiling?

I'd like to make hop tea with some LME, lets say about 5l(1.3 gallons) and mix it with warm water and LME.

This may prevent me from waiting long time before wort get cold.

Comment: Google "No boil beer recipe." You should find what you're looking for.

Comment: If you use a pre-hopped liquid extract you don't need to boil at all.

Comment: @nullability I'm using unhopped extract.

Answer (score 2):

Boiling extract achieves a few things. Most important it kills many bacteria and wild yeast that might have made it's way into the wort. Even with properly sanitised equipment there is a risk that there is something in the water or even drifting in the air.

Also boiling the extract will also make it darker and change the flavour a bit, so when you do this cold you will get a different beer.

As mentioned on some of the other answers you will not get much bitterness out of the hop unless you boil it, but you can still get aroma by dry hopping. You could make a hop tea as you suggest. Note that the amount of water you boil hop in affect how much your able to extract from it.

Another thing to consider is to boil the extract and most of the water, then cool it down rapidly by dumping ice into it. That way you remove the bacteria and yeast in the wort by boiling. At the same time you can boil the hops. Normally you would boil hops 30-60 minutes to get bitterness, and less to get aroma. Extract on the other hand is usually only boiled 10 minutes.

I also want to mention that some of the wort chiller are very good and easy to use, and in the end might be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the water to at least 160 for a few minutes to pasteurize it. Another reason to heat it up is to help thin out the thick and syrupy LME. Also, if you want to extract any bitterness from the hops you'll have to boil them for at least 15 minutes to isomerize the alpha acids. The more bitterness you want the longer you need to boil, hence Dogfish Head's 60 and 90 Minute IPAs.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to get your wort cool faster, buy or make a wort chiller. It's basically a coil of copper tubing with a hose at either end that you can attach to a hose or a sink spigot. You immerse the chiller in your wort, right in the pot, and you turn on the water. Cold water runs through, absorbs the heat from the wort, and runs right back out. I can take a wort from a rolling boil to 64F in about thirty minutes.

Answer (score -5):

You may also know that it is not possible to get Extract without boiling malts.
Try to put malts in cold area to make them colder fast.